# Async Multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

Hi I am trying to send this processing to different cores as they are all independent of one another, however none of them are awaiting so the tasks never run. I thought that was what futures were for?

```py
async def process_object(filename):
    # await 1 - download file from S3
    
    # await 2 - parse XML file

if "__main__" == __name__:
    objects = get_objects(
        bucket_name=bucket_name, prefix=prefix, file_extension=".xml", top_n=top_n
    )

    futures = []
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(
        multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    ) as executor:
        futures = [executor.submit(process_object, filename) for filename in objects]
    concurrent.futures.wait(futures)
```

Comment: At the risk of having this go on forever, I too deleted the comment you were responding to :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `asyncio` if you're submitting a task to `ProcessPoolExecutor`. Those tasks will be executed in another process so they are already running concurrently without the use of asyncio. Your `process_object` function never runs with your current code because a coroutine must be `awaited` before it will execute.

That is, you want something like:

```
def process_object(filename):
    # download file
    # parse file    
    ...

if "__main__" == __name__:
    objects = get_objects(
        bucket_name=bucket_name, prefix=prefix, file_extension=".xml", top_n=top_n
    )

    futures = []
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(
        multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    ) as executor:
        futures = [executor.submit(process_object, filename) for filename in objects]
    concurrent.futures.wait(futures)
```

Comment: Ah ok, here is the thing though: I need to await the download from S3 before I can then parse the file, therefore I prefaced the function with async otherwise I cannot await.

Comment: Why do you need to `await` the S3 download? Just make a synchronous call instead of an async call. You're not getting any benefit from `asyncio` in this case.

Comment: You are right I messed that up, a subprocess call will block until it is finished downloading, however the parse part exits very quickly